# Software audio mixing

Tags: c++, audio, mixing

I'm looking into learning how software mixing works in general (methods, best practices, pitfalls, etc...) so if anyone has any good c++ literature on the subject that explains how it works, it would be much appreciated.

I've already seen the small explanation at: [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/77577/) but I was looking for something more in depth. In that line, can anyone provide a good explanation on software mixing?

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 waveforms represented with their data in some form of an array, say of `short` values, you just have to ADD those values and resulting array is 'mixed' audio.

Here it is: [Programmatically merging two pieces of audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126169/programmatically-merging-two-pieces-of-audio/5126209#5126209)